# Passing data between two pages using SQFlite in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have two pages with each page containing one `TextFormField`. I want to store data entered in first page and display it in the second page and so on. I want this to happen using Database(Sqflite). I'm unable to figure out on how to store two different values belonging to the same row of a single Database table.

Comment: Use classes with static attributes, you can go with the data and rescue them from any place or other activity

Comment: I know the normal procedure of creating a database. I know the insertion into a table when all the entries into the table are in the same page. But here my entries are in different pages. Can you please elaborate if this is what you are talking about?

Comment: First of all Pages are UI and data should not be stored in UI. The only data that should be stored in UI is the one that is required for the State of a widget. Use bloc pattern instead. Access database through bloc and connect your pages to the bloc. one page will give input that should be stored in database thorough bloc and another page should read from the bloc. Does this help ?? let me know in case of any doubt

Comment: Thanks, I understood what you said. Is there a way to implement that without Bloc? I need it to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since the app requires multiple pages, I think `PageView` would be the best for this case.

For the answer to your question checkout below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewDemoState createState() => _PageViewDemoState();
}

class _PageViewDemoState extends State<PageViewDemo> {
  Map<String, bool> _importantData;
  List<String> _pages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _importantData = Map<String, bool>();
    _pages = <String>['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      children: _pages.map<Widget>((String pageText) {
        return Center(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  pageText.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text('isChecked: '),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  value: _importantData[pageText] ?? false,
                  onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _importantData[pageText] = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** This code is just for an explanation, It is not meant to be used directly for the solution.

As you can see, there are 4 different pages with checkboxes for each page. The map `_importantData` is used for storing the checked status for each page.

Just like _importantData`to store the checked status, any model class instance can be used for storing the data. Like`_importantData`, any model class can store data that needs to be accessed across all the pages.

For example, you can create a data class to store values that user will input on each page. Just make sure to create a single instance of the model class and pass it through each page to access/update relative values.